# Lower bound minimum eigenvalue of a positive semi-definite Hermitian matrix with bounded entries

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, random-matrices, eigenvalues, matrix-analysis

Let $M \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ be a matrix with the following properties:

1. $M$ is Hermitian and positive semi-definite (all the eigenvalues are real and nonnegative).
2. The diagonal entries of $M$ are all $1$.
3. The off-diagonal entries all have magnitude at most $\epsilon \in [0, \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}]$.

I need to lower bound the minimum eigenvalue $\lambda_{\rm{min}}$ in terms of $n$ and $\epsilon$.

I know, via the [Gershgorin circle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem), that all the eigenvalues are within $1 \pm (n-1)\epsilon$, but that is useless unless $\epsilon < \frac{1}{n-1}$, which is not true for the matrix $M$ above.

Note also that for $\epsilon = 0$, all the eigenvalues are trivially $1$.

Does anyone have any techniques/ideas that may achieve a better bound?

Comment: You say that you want a lower bound on $\lambda_{min}$, but you also say that you're hoping to show that $\lambda_{min}$ approaches zero. Is it really a lower bound that you want, or an upper bound?

Comment: A lower bound. Sorry, that statement is unclear. I will try to edit it.

Comment: In that case I'm not sure you can do any better than the Gershgorin bound that you already noted. Let $\epsilon = 1/(n-1)$ and consider the matrix $M$ with diagonal entries $1$ and off-diagonal entries $-\epsilon$. This matrix satisfies all 3 of your requirements and has minimum eigenvalue equal to $0$.

Comment: I am not sure to understand the third statement. Do you mean that all the off-diagonal entries belong to that interval?

Comment: The third statement is saying that the magnitude of the $(i,j)$ entry for $i \neq j$ is at most $\epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is some number between $0$ and $1/\sqrt{2}$ (but the magnitudes of each off-diagonal entry are not necessarily equal).

Comment: @NathanielJohnston is that matrix PSD? I will check later today.

Comment: Yes, it's actually a multiple of an orthogonal projection (onto the orthogonal complement of the all-ones vector). And even if it weren't, you could just decrease its entries further to make it PSD with a 0 eigenvalue, since there is some path from that matrix to the identity matrix and eigenvalues are continuous functions of the matrix entries.

Comment: Nathaniel's example (with $0\le\epsilon\le 1/(n-1)$) also shows that the Gershgorin bound is sharp.